# Want to learn about Views in drupal?

Tags: drupal

i want to learn about views, CCK in drupal. Whetheer its best to read the online docs or there is any books, links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cck

http://drupal.org/node/101723

For views

http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/views

Also would suggest you use the advance help module (can't use a hyperlink as am not allowed more than 2 :() as it has some great views resources or else u can access it from here

views-help.doc.logrus.com

Answer (score 2):

Of course, online docs are one of the best. You can also checkout the videos at http://learnbythedrop.com/cckandviews

Answer (score 1):

Lullabot has a [Learning Views video](http://store.lullabot.com/products/learning-views) that is also available [through their drupalize.me site](http://drupalize.me/videos/learning-views-drupal). Their [Using Drupal](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596515804) book is also an excellent resource.